# three.js with customization

Tags: three.js, html5-canvas

Is it possible to add a model(say ,a mobile phone) using three.js in html5 canvas and then make it customizable like adding text,image etc.( on mobile ) using any canvas library,so as to make an interactive 3d model.
Thanks.

Comment: @antont,@ezekg : Thanks for your help.But I want something like present in  https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=bAZR-IPxbag.As we have a 3d model(in example mobile phone) and then we are customizing it in the required way. Is there any way to achieve this?

Answer (score 0):

You could use a library called [Dat.GUI](https://github.com/dataarts/dat.gui), which allows you to create a quick user interface that can accept plain text input fields, drop downs, select boxes, as well as numerical sliders. [Here's an example of it being used with a text input field](http://workshop.chromeexperiments.com/examples/gui/#3--Folders), which you could use to input a texture/image URL.

It's a really powerful library that can be further styled with CSS, if needed. This is all the code you need to get up and running (as you can see below, the object's properties get modified directly by Dat.GUI via invoking `gui.add(object, 'property')`):

```
<script type="text/javascript" src="dat.gui.js"></script>
<script type="text/javascript">

var FizzyText = function() {
  this.message = 'dat.gui';
  this.speed = 0.8;
  this.displayOutline = false;
  this.explode = function() { ... };
  // Define render logic ...
};

window.onload = function() {
  var text = new FizzyText();
  var gui = new dat.GUI();
  gui.add(text, 'message');
  gui.add(text, 'speed', -5, 5);
  gui.add(text, 'displayOutline');
  gui.add(text, 'explode');
};

</script>
```

Answer (score 0):

Yes. Three.js uses a canvas to render the 3D things and you can use any HTML tools to make the rest of that web page how you want.